# Compare java source to bytecode

Tags: java

I inherited a java project but have a been given a few version of the source code, and am not sure witch one is the live version.

Is there a way to compare the source code to the class files to see which one matches?

PS. how does the intelij debugger know if there is a source mismatch? Can i run that test globally on all the class files?

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question. When you figure it out be sure to use version control, such as Git, so that you don't have this problem again in the future.

Comment: I remember java complaining of source/class file version mismatch in case of our model classes being out of date on the client. So it has to store some kind of version information in .class I guess..

Comment: match the dates of all the version of the source code with the live version release date

Comment: Or to phrase better, it did complain that library version is other one compared to library our model classes were compiled against.

Comment: I'd try to compile the source, then decompile all .class files, then check for diffs

Comment: Compile the source code and then compare the `.classes`

Comment: I'd start out by checking for classes that are/are not in each source version, then checking the class files in production to see which classes match. Doesn't work for minor changes of course, but if you have `Foo.class` in production, and only one source has `Foo.java` it's an easy hit.

Comment: The debugger can know there's a mismatch because it has access to the bytecode being run, and bytecode dynamically compiled from the source.

Answer (score 1):

There is `javap` to disassemble class files to text. With many options to show the methods' instructions and such. Compiling the source code with the same compiler should give similar java bytecode sources.

Comment: can you share some examples of same?

Comment: Is there a way to get the original compile options from the class files? Is the version of javac important?

Comment: The java version can be taken from the major/minor version: major - 44 = the java version, 52 would be java 8. Then debugging info can be ommitted, line numbers only, with local names. And so on. Hand work.